# Unable to open phpmyadmin directory: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to log into `phpmyadmin page` from a `localhost`, but whenever I try to open the `phpmyadmin directory`, I get the following message...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function __() in C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\sanitizing.lib.php:135 Stack trace: #0 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\Message.php(586): PMA_sanitize('Undefined index...', false, true) #1 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\Message.php(650): PMA\libraries\Message::decodeBB('Undefined index...') #2 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\Error.php(167): PMA\libraries\Message->getMessage() #3 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\ErrorHandler.php(157): PMA\libraries\Error->getHash() #4 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\ErrorHandler.php(121): PMA\libraries\ErrorHandler->addError('Undefined index...', 8, 'C:\dev\www\pma\...', 285, true) #5 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\core.lib.php(285): PMA\libraries\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', 'C:\dev\www\pma\...', 285, Array) #6 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\core.lib.php(312): PMA_getPHPDocLink('book.mbstring.p...') #7 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\core.lib.php(954): PMA_warnMissingExtension('mbstring', true) #8 C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\common.inc.php(97): PMA_checkExtensions() #9 C:\dev in C:\dev\www\pma\libraries\sanitizing.lib.php on line 135

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Just had this. Needs the php-mbstring extension installed.

Comment: you also need to restart Apache after installation of php-mbstring

Answer (score 0):

This could be a multitude of things. Typically this occurs due to the permissions you have set for the PHPMyAdmin directory. Assuming you manually compiled/installed PHP (as opposed to using an out-of-the-box solution such as XAMPP), it would do you well to ensure that the following extensions are enabled within your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=mbstring.dll
extension=mysqli.dll
```

Take the time while doing so to verify that the `extension_dir` property is also properly set. Remember to fully restart Apache using `httpd -k stop` and `httpd -k start` in order for changes made to `php.ini` or other configuration files to take effect as `httpd -k restart` sometimes doesn't propagate the changes.