# I am unable to run PHPmyadmin on apache because of this error

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

This is what comes up when I try to go to localhost/phpmyadmin. I have tried restarting Apache and my browser multiple times. I am just setting all of this up for the first time, so I'm not really sure how to phrase my question, and I don't really understand what the error is telling me, so any clarification on that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function __() in C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\sanitizing.lib.php:135
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\Message.php(586): PMA_sanitize('Undefined index...', false, true)
#1 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\Message.php(650): PMA\libraries\Message::decodeBB('Undefined index...')
#2 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\Error.php(167): PMA\libraries\Message->getMessage()
#3 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\ErrorHandler.php(157): PMA\libraries\Error->getHash()
#4 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\ErrorHandler.php(121): PMA\libraries\ErrorHandler->addError('Undefined index...', 8, 'C:\\Apache\\htdoc...', 285, true)
#5 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(285): PMA\libraries\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', 'C:\\Apache\\htdoc...', 285, Array) #6 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(312): PMA_getPHPDocLink('book.mbstring.p...')
#7 C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(954): PMA_warnM in C:\Apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\sanitizing.lib.php on line 135
```

I am very new to programming, so I apologize if this is something that was resolved before. I am still unsure how to phrase many of my questions to get the results that I am looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you have all PHPMyAdmin files extracted correctly? It has nothing to do with Apache, just missing function. Maybe forgot/modified some files?

Comment: I just deleted it and tried redownloading and re-extracting the file back into htdocs. I restarted apache and tried to open it again and got the same error. I am using the phpmyadmin.net 4.6.0 download from their site.

Comment: The error only happens when I open the http.conf file and change index.html to index.php. Otherwise, localhost will open phpmyadmin and display all of the elements inside of it as a list.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and removing any phpMyAdmin cookies (which start with "pma").

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow this suggestion 
[Unable to open phpmyadmin directory: Call to undefined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294886/unable-to-open-phpmyadmin-directory-call-to-undefined-function) 
It worked for me.

> [...] ensure that the following extensions are enabled within your `php.ini` file:
>
> > `extension=php_bz2.dll`
> >     `extension=mbstring.dll`
> >     `extension=mysqli.dll`
>
> Take the time while doing so to verify that the `extension_dir` property is also properly set. Remember to fully restart Apache using `httpd -k stop` and `httpd -k start` in order for changes made to *php.ini* or other configuration files to take effect as `httpd -k restart` sometimes doesn't propagate the changes.